# Side menu on button click in Android

Tags: android, google-drive-api, slidingmenu

I am trying to implement a feature in android which is used in Google Drive app. When you click on the info button of one of your file you get a sliding menu on the right. You can find the image [here](https://lh6.ggpht.com/blhSEz5VfVL4hCCRgGNZQPGMGXPXzKAbNIwasvvewu8PCmHHBIGfyAunXZ6KHe0yP2aW=h900-rw). I don't know if this is a custom implementation of Sliding Menu or if a class exists to do this. Appreciate if anyone could help me implement this. I want this on a button click and the list view should appear from right.

Comment: Are you looking for [Navigation Drawer ?](https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a [`DrawerLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html). The View you add with `android:layout_gravity="end"` will be at the right.

To open it on click, use `drawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravitiy.END);`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to implement [Navigation Drawer.](https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html) You can find a sample ready to run application from [Android Developer Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/shareables/training/NavigationDrawer.zip)